# Defining a struct error in VS 2015

Tags: c, visual-studio, struct

I have a struct declaration in my header

```
#ifndef _MAP_IMPL_
typedef struct { } *MapADT;
#endif
```

And I then define it in my source file like this

```
typedef struct Key {

    void * value;
    void * keyVal;
    struct Key * next;
} Key;

    // Defining struct MapADT
typedef struct {
    Key *keys; // Head of keys
    bool (*equals)( const void *a, const void *b );

}*MapADT;

#define _MAP_IMPL_
#include "mapADT.h" // Header file
```

This works perfectly fine on Linux, but for some reason VS really hates it.
Is there any work around to this?

Visual Studio gives me an error indicating that

"C requires that a struct or union has at least one member"

Comment: gcc 4.5.2 isn't fond of this at all.

Comment: Yeah I've noticed, thats why I'm asking if any of you sharp people have found a work around. I'm sure I'm not the only one who has experienced this...

Comment: linux + gcc does not like this at all.  Suggest re-designing the data.